# Having to press submit button a few times in java web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, submit

I have a java web application and I am submitting some data in one of the forms using a submit button. I use servlets. However, I am having to press the submit button a few times before I reach the next step. I would have uploaded the code or provided some more information but I'm not sure which part to upload and I've no idea what this issue is about. Can someone advise me as to how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd do is open up FireBug if you're using Firefox, or press F12 for IE. From there you'll be able to see the requests being sent to the server and the response. Keep an eye on those as you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful tool for working with requests:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

It is a FireFox add on, but monitors all the requests and lets you change them before they are sent.